# Is there better way to transpose a PHP 2D array?

Tags: php, arrays

According to the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), calling `array_map` with a `NULL` callback causes it to perform a "zip" function, creating an array of arrays of parallel elements from the given arrays.

For example:

```
array_map(NULL,array(1,2,3),array('a','b','c'));
```

yields

```
array(array(1,'a'),array(2,'b'),array(3,'c'))
```

This is also equivalent to transposing the array

```
array(array(1,2,3),array('a','b','c'))
```

Right now, it appears this is the closest way (using built-in functions) you can transpose an array, except that `array_map` takes a list of arrays, not an array of arrays.

In some code I am working on, I need to transpose an array of arrays, not a list of arrays, so I made this work-around:

```
call_user_func_array('array_map',array_merge(array(NULL),$array_of_arrays))
```

However, this feels very dirty and clumsy.

And so I ask:
**Is there a better way to transpose a 2D array with PHP, aside from a custom implementation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. That's the most elegant.

Answer (score 4):

**Update for PHP 5.6:**

We can take advantage of PHP 5.6's "splat" operator to make this operation much, much cleaner with argument unpacking:

```
array_map(null, ...$array_of_arrays);
```

For example:

```
[1] boris> $arr2d = [ [1,2,3], ['a','b','c'] ];
// array(
//   0 => array(
//     0 => 1,
//     1 => 2,
//     2 => 3
//   ),
//   1 => array(
//     0 => 'a',
//     1 => 'b',
//     2 => 'c'
//   )
// )
[2] boris> array_map(null, ...$arr2d);
// array(
//   0 => array(
//     0 => 1,
//     1 => 'a'
//   ),
//   1 => array(
//     0 => 2,
//     1 => 'b'
//   ),
//   2 => array(
//     0 => 3,
//     1 => 'c'
//   )
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid the `array_merge`, use `array_unshift` to prepend the NULL to the `$array_of_arrays` instead:

```
array_unshift($array_of_arrays, NULL);
call_user_func_array('array_map', $array_of_arrays);
```

Of course it is not a one-liner anymore :P

Comment: And it alters `$array_of_arrays` if I would want to use it later, so I would have to `array_shift($array_of_arrays)` afterwards...

Comment: @Austin Hyde: true. you can just make a copy of the array: `$array_of_arrays = $my_arrays_of_arrays` beforehand