# Transpose an associative array containing indexed elements

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I've got an array which looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  ["file"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "company_handbook_2011.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "test.doc"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "test.doc"
  }
  ["status"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "SHOW"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "HIDE"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "HIDE"
  }
}
```

how can i rearrange it to look like this:

```
array(
    array(
        "one",
        "company_handbook_2011.pdf",
        "SHOW"
    ),
    array(
        "two",
        "test.doc",
        "HIDE"
    ),
    array(
        "test",
        "test.doc",
        "HIDE"
    ),      
)
```

i.e get the first element of each array and and build a new array and then the second element  and so on. Thank very much for your help.

Comment: There's no ready-made function for this I think. You'll have to simply walk through the array in a loop, and build it

Comment: You don't necessarly have to walk through the array since the indexes seem to match between your different keys. You could count the number `$array['title']` and then use a simple for loop that gets the values from the right positions to construct a new array. Would be interesting to benchmark which method is faster.

Comment: some useful information from you guys thanks very much...appreciate your time. array_map did the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are searching for is called the *transpose* of a matrix. Here is a previous answer on StackOverflow:

[Is there better way to transpose a PHP 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460022/is-there-better-way-to-transpose-a-php-2d-array)

I take the liberty to directly copy the solution from that thread ($array_of_arrays is your original array, $transposed_array is the result):

```
$transposed_array = call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge(array(NULL), $array_of_arrays));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($origArray['title'] as $k => $title) {
    $flatArr[] = array($title, $origArray['file'][$k], $origArray['status'][$k]);
}
```