# Get max value from each column of a 2-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, max, array-column

I have an array within an array, for example:

```
[ 
    [0, 20, 5], 
    [5, 0, 15], 
    [5, 10, 0]
]
```

I need to get the max number in each column.

- The max of `[0 , 5 , 5]` is `5`, so that goes into the result array.
- The max of `[20, 0, 10]` is `20`, so that goes into the result array.
- The max of `[5, 15, 0]` is `15`, so that goes into the result array.

The final result array must contain `[5, 20, 15]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the array has to be transposed (flip the rows and columns):

```
function array_transpose($arr) {
   $map_args = array_merge(array(NULL), $arr);
   return call_user_func_array('array_map', $map_args);
}
```

(taken from [Is there better way to transpose a PHP 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460022/is-there-better-way-to-transpose-a-php-2d-array) - read that question for an explanation of how it works)

Then, you can map the `max` function on the new array:

```
$maxes = array_map('max', array_transpose($arr));
```

Example: http://codepad.org/3gPExrhO

Output [I think this is what you meant instead of (5, 15, 20) because you said index 1 should be max of (20, 0, 10)]:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the splat operator, `array_map()` with `max()` will return the max value for each row. (`[20, 15, 10]`)

With the splat operator to transpose the data structure, the max value for each column is returned.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pp1D4))

```
$array = [ 
    [0, 20, 5], 
    [5, 0, 15], 
    [5, 10, 0]
];

var_export(
    array_map('max', ...$array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 5,
  1 => 20,
  2 => 15,
)
```